# Comparing items in 2 lists in c#

Tags: c#, list, compare, iteration

I have 2 lists that I'm currently working with. I need to compare the items in the lists to each other, but I dont want to compare every item with every other item, just the items that are in the same index position in the corresponding list.

So it might look like:

```
List1.item1 == List2.item1
List1.item2 == List2.item2
List1.item3 == List2.item3
```

and return true or false for each one. I was going to use a foreach loop, but I can't figure out how to iterate through both lists at the same time, comparing along the way. I don't have any code right now to share because I don't know where to start. Could use any help on where to go to look for resources or code examples.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just iterate them through index? Is there any concern about that?

Comment: A simple for loop indexing the lists maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [Zip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=netframework-4.7#System_Linq_Enumerable_Zip__3_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___1__System_Func___0___1___2__) extension method.

```
var result = firstList.Zip(secondList, (a, b) => a == b);
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < List1.Count; i++) //iterate over each possible index
{
    if (List1[i] == List2[i])
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

You should handle the case which `List1` and `List2` don't have the same number of items, like that for example: `i < Math.Min(List1.Count, List2.Count)`, so don't go out of boundary on some list.

Comment: LINQ's Zip method handles the merging until it reaches the end of one of the sequences. But your implementation is the best possible answer to the OP.

Comment: I didnt try this way but i understand the thought. In my case they are never going to be different lengths, but I can see why you'd want to do this to put contingencies in place. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Another option, you could utilizing the [except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx) extension.

```
var difference = collection.Except(samples).ToList();
```

Similar to zip, but returns the differences between the list.  Not sure if this is a valid use for your scenario, but it does work well.